# Resolve AvoidLiteralsInIfCondition in interface default method

Tags: java, pmd

The PMD rule [`AvoidLiteralsInIfCondition`](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_java_errorprone.html#avoidliteralsinifcondition) flags a problem whenever a literal (e.g. 7, 10) is used in a condition (e.g. `if (x > 7)`).  In a class, I typically solve this by creating a `private static final` to hold the value.  However, if the literal is used in an interface's default method, I cannot create a `private static final` in the interface.  How do I fix the `AvoidLiteralsInIfCondition`?

I know I could use `// NOPMD` or `@SuppressWarnings` but that does not fix the problem.  I do not benefit from clearer code by using a `private static final`.

Here is some code that demonstrates the problem.

```
public interface UTF8Length
{
   default int getUTF8Length(char value)
   {
      if (value <= 0x007F)  // PMD flags a problem with 0x007F
         return 1;

      if (value <= 0x07FF)  // PMD flags a problem with 0x07FF
         return 2;

      return 3;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in the OP comments, you could externalize your constants to an external class:

```
public class ConstantHelper {
    public static final int TWO_BYTE_MAX_CP = 0x7FF;
}
```

Then in your interface's default method you could do this without offending PMD:

```
if (value <= ConstantHelper.TWO_BYTE_MAX_CP) { // No PMD issue with this.
    return 2;
}
```

That's probably fine for your example, but there are a couple of guiding principles:

- Externalizing a constant to a constants class is not a good approach if that constant is only an implementation detail for your interface, and is unlikely to ever be used by any other classes or interfaces. Creating a new constants class solely to remove a PMD warning is a questionable approach.
- Externalizing a constant to a constants class is not a good approach if the value might change in the future, because that change might also impact other classes. In this case it looks like you are referring to Unicode values that will almost certainly never change, so that is not an issue here.

An alternative approach is to have a local declarations within your default method, and use those:

```
default int getUTF8Length(char value) {

    final int oneByteMaxCP = 0x007F; // PMD flags AvoidFinalLocalVariables

    if (value <= oneByteMaxCP) { 
        return 1;
    }

    final int twoByteMaxCP = 0x007FF; // PMD flags AvoidFinalLocalVariables

    if (value <= twoByteMaxCP) { 
        return 2;
    }

    return 3;
}
```

If you do that you will offend PMD in a different way ("*AvoidFinalLocalVariable: Avoid using final local variables, turn them into fields*") but the advantages are:

- You don't need an external class.
- I find the code slightly clearer, though that is personal taste.
- Those local declarations are self documenting, and - unlike comments - they must be correct for the code to work properly.
- Those local declarations are completely private. This might not be a benefit for your specific example, but it is easy to imagine other scenarios where you want to use constants in a default method, and not share them with anyone else.

So if the constant values you want to externalize don't violate the two principles described above then create a constants class. Otherwise, declare your constants locally, and accept that you will get *AvoidFinalLocalVariable* warnings from PMD, because writing clear, clean and maintainable code is more important than removing PMD warnings.